# Maximum Size of QPixmap/QImage Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, qt

I have a QGraphicsView for a very wide QGraphicsScene. I need to draw the background in drawBackground() and the background is a bit complicated (long loop) although it doesn't need to be repainted constantly. I store it in a static QPixmap (I tried QImage too) inside the function drawBackground() and that pixmap is what I draw onto the painter of the view. Only when needed is the QPixmap painted on again.

If I didn't use a static pixmap, the complicated background would be generated every time I scroll sideways for example. The problem is that apparently there is a maximum width for pixmaps on Windows, on my computer it's 32770. I could store a list of pixmaps and draw them side by side but it would make the code uglier and I also don't know what the maximum width of a pixmap is for every Windows machine. Since this might be a well-known problem I was wondering if anyone has a better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid the windows limit by using unaccelerated raster paint device, but 32770*1024 is 100MiB of pixmap; you probably don't want to do that even if Windows would let you.

You've already thought of the usual answer (tile it in more reasonably-sized chunks and load/generate them on demand). The other piece of the usual solution is to use something like QPixmapCache to keep the recently-used tiles so you don't regenerate them too often (only when the user scrolls a long way).

You didn't say how complex your complex background is, but you might also want to look at the Mandelbrot set example for how to do piecewise rendering of an (infinitely) large background pixmap on-demand, without blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is the common use case for the tiling pattern. Basically you split the background into small images.

I'm not sure why you think "it would make the code uglier". It is certainly not a one-liner. Depending whether you have fixed size background image or not, the tiling code is usually pretty straightforward.